# merge two data table into one, with alternating columns in R

Tags: r, join, merge

I have two data tables, `odd_data` and `even_data`. I would like to combine/merge them into one, `all_data` where the odd columns of `all_data` are the columns of `odd_data` and even columns of it are columns of `even_data`. However, what I try throws an error.

Lets say the `odd_data` and `even_data` look like :

```
odd_data
   col_1 col_3
    11    13
    21    23
    31    33

even_data
  col_2 col_4
    12    14
    22    24
    32    34
```

Where the desired result looks like:

```
all_data
   col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4
    11    12    13    14
    21    22    23    24
    31    32    33    34
```

What I have tried is the following:

```
odd_data = data.table(col_1 = c(11, 21, 31),
                      col_3 = c(13, 23, 33))


even_data = data.table(col_2 = c(12, 22, 32),
                       col_4 = c(14, 24, 34))

all_data <- data.table(matrix(nrow = nrow(odd_data), ncol = (ncol(odd_data)*2)))
# change the name of columns of all_data to match column names of odd/even_data
colnames_data <- colnames(all_data)
setnames(all_data, old=colnames_data[c(TRUE, FALSE)], new= colnames(odd_data))
setnames(all_data, old=colnames_data[c(FALSE, TRUE)], new= colnames(even_data))

all_data[, c(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 2))] <- odd_data
```

The error is

```
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , c(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 2)), value = list( : 
  j must be vector of column name or positions
```

Comment: Another possibiliy: `d <- cbind(odd_data, even_data)`; `setcolorder(d, c(matrix(1:ncol(d), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just `cbind` them and then re-order the columns:

```r
neworder <- order(c(2*(seq_along(odd_data) - 1) + 1,
                    2*seq_along(even_data)))
cbind(odd_data, even_data)[,neworder]
#    col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4
# 1:    11    12    13    14
# 2:    21    22    23    24
# 3:    31    32    33    34
```

---

Explanation:

```r
### count by odds
2*(seq_along(odd_data) - 1) + 1
# [1] 1 3

### count by evens
2*seq_along(even_data)
# [1] 2 4

neworder
# [1] 1 3 2 4
```

This gives us the column order we want in the end: first column (`col_1`), third column (`col_2`, since it is after all columns of the first table), etc.

To test, we can generate two asymmetric examples:

```r
odd_data = data.table(col_1 = c(11, 21, 31),
                      col_3 = c(13, 23, 33),
                      col_5 = c(15, 25, 35))
even_data = data.table(col_2 = c(12, 22, 32),
                       col_4 = c(14, 24, 34))
neworder <- order(c(2*(seq_along(odd_data) - 1) + 1,
                    2*seq_along(even_data)))
cbind(odd_data, even_data)[,neworder]
#    col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5
# 1:    11    12    13    14    15
# 2:    21    22    23    24    25
# 3:    31    32    33    34    35
```

Next, 3 and 3:

```r
odd_data = data.table(col_1 = c(11, 21, 31),
                      col_3 = c(13, 23, 33),
                      col_5 = c(15, 25, 35))
even_data = data.table(col_2 = c(12, 22, 32),
                       col_4 = c(14, 24, 34),
                       col_6 = c(16, 26, 36))

neworder <- order(c(2*(seq_along(odd_data) - 1) + 1,
                    2*seq_along(even_data)))
cbind(odd_data, even_data)[,neworder]
#    col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5 col_6
# 1:    11    12    13    14    15    16
# 2:    21    22    23    24    25    26
# 3:    31    32    33    34    35    36
```

Now if we want to try to mess up the system by having more *evens* than *odds* (which "shouldn't" happen):

```r
odd_data = data.table(col_1 = c(11, 21, 31),
                      col_3 = c(13, 23, 33),
                      col_5 = c(15, 25, 35))
even_data = data.table(col_2 = c(12, 22, 32),
                       col_4 = c(14, 24, 34),
                       col_6 = c(16, 26, 36),
                       col_8 = c(18, 28, 38))

neworder <- order(c(2*(seq_along(odd_data) - 1) + 1,
                    2*seq_along(even_data)))
cbind(odd_data, even_data)[,neworder]
#    col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5 col_6 col_8
# 1:    11    12    13    14    15    16    18
# 2:    21    22    23    24    25    26    28
# 3:    31    32    33    34    35    36    38
```

So while `col_8` is not technically the 8th column, the order of all other columns is still preserved.

Comment: :D that was simple! 
I always take weird routes!

Answer (score 0):

you can use bind_cols from dplyr package like this

```
bind_cols(odd_data,even_data)[,c(1,3,2,4)]
```